# Background image is on top of H1

Tags: html, css, background

The h1 goes behind the background-image. I've tried using z-index and position:absolute and relative but nothing changed. How do I make the background image to remain a background forever without having to make every other element to be added on top of it?

```css
body {
background-image: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/396538.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hotoi Sebastian | Front-End Developer & Web Designer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="text">
        <h1>Sebastian Hotoi</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There must be an issue that we cant recreate. If you put a background-image to the body it is in the background. If the text doesnt show up its most likely not behind the image. it doesnt get displayed at all

Comment: I've removed position:absolute but it still doesn't make the text to appear over the background. Am I setting up the background incorrectly? Shouldn't the image be in the body via css?

Comment: You can see the background image but not the text? Is that correct?

Comment: This sounds stupid to ask but are you sure the heading is behind? Can you provide a jsfiddle for us to see?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u81xwzfL/1/ The thing is that the file is on my local computer so the jsfiddle won't render it

Comment: @alasdair009 when loading with live server, I can see the text for a second just before the background image loads

Comment: i cant think of any reason why the text should just disappear. Try to give it a very highlighted color like Red or yellow, and then when you loaded the page in a Browser use the DEV-Tools to make sure that the div with the text is there at all

Comment: I've added an actual image URL so that you can test it now ( was a local image before) @Paulie_D

Comment: uhm... your image is black.. and the text is black. its there you just cant see it :)

Comment: @Warden330 you are totally right. due to the color, I wasn't able to see it, I've changed to white and it's visible. I feel so stupid now...

Comment: haha dont worry, you are definetly not the only one that happened to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Black Image with black Text is the issue here... add the Color: white in css

```css
body {
background-image: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/396538.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

.text {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hotoi Sebastian | Front-End Developer & Web Designer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="text">
        <h1>Sebastian Hotoi</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid making the body position absolute.

If you want the background behind the heading that should be the default without making it absolute our using any z-index. Make sure it is not a case of the image being the same colour as the text and just making it look like it is not there :)